# Populating a table with AJAX response

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

My AJAX response contains the elements of a database. I have a table on my page `#people` and as the AJAX request succeeds, I need to populate my table with the database records. This is the code I am using (that is a `<script>` in my `index.html`):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "res/main.php",
            data: { command : "loadPeople" },
            success: function( resp ){
                for(var i = 1; i<= people.length; i++){
                    var tableRow = "<tr><td>" + people[i].id + "</td><td>" + people[i].name + "</td></tr>";
                    $("#people > tbody:last").append(tableRow);
                }
                console.log(resp.people);
            }
    });
});
```

(the code I am using to fill the table is taken from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery))

I am using FireBug in Chrome, and when I refresh the page, nothing appears in its console, and my table is unchanged. What can I do to solve this error? Where is the error?

EDIT:

I renamed `resp` to `people`, now my table is being populated with about one thousand items labeled `undefined`.

This is a sample of my `people`:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Victor "},{"id":"2","name":"Dan "},{"id":"3","name":"John"},{"id":"4","name":"Mady"},{"id":"5","name":"Mary"},{"id":"6","name":"Michael"},{"id":"7","name":"Michaela"}]
```

(encoded in PHP)

Comment: and *please* read the jquery docs.. you're using old syntax here.

Comment: my mistake was stupid, but since I have renamed the `resp` to `people` my table was filled with about 1000 items labeled `undefined`

Comment: please, do not downvote, I am totally new to jQuery, I am only trying to learn...

Comment: Post sample of how looks 'people'.

Comment: what is the response you are getting try -> console.log(resp)

Answer (score 0):

try change

```
 success: function( resp ){
```

with

```
 success: function( people){
```

Answer (score 0):

I found where my problem was. Inside the `$.ajax` request, I had to specify `dataType : "json"`. Now my table is correctly populated, and the console looks good.